# Android Work Manager - Does Work Manager will 100% ensure the background execution to be Completed?

Tags: android, workmanagers, android-workmanager

From what I read from the documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager,

**It said that:**

> The task is still guaranteed to run, even if your app is force-quit or
>   the device is rebooted.

So which mean, the execution that being at the background will 100% be execute until it complete no matter what?

**For an example case:**

An Apps have Button that perform Work Manager Implementation that upload data to an Online Database but it **required Internet Connection** to upload the data. So, my Apps is currently **in Offline Mode** and I click the Button.

**My Uncertainty:**

Will the Work Manager run the process at background, and **keep retrying the process** even when there is no Internet Connection? and only **complete and stop the process** until there is an Internet Connection and complete the data upload?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Will the Work Manager run the process at background, and keep retrying
>   the process even when there is no Internet Connection? and only
>   complete and stop the process until there is an Internet Connection
>   and complete the data upload?

It won't implicitly try to execute the work continuously and stop only if it was successful. It will depend on Result returned by `doWork()` or your `Worker`. If it returns `RETRY`, then the work will be  retried with backoff specified in `WorkRequest.Builder.setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy, long, TimeUnit)`.

However, if you need something to be executed when there is internet connection, then you can specify the appropriate constraints. For network connectivity, you can set constraints as follows:

```
Constraints myConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
.setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
.build();

 OneTimeWorkRequest mywork=
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
 .setConstraints(myConstraints)
 .build();
 WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mywork);
```

`WorkManager` will ensure that your work is executed only if there is internet connection.

Comment: when i ad this constraint work manager not upload the image, but my mobile connected to wifi . any idea why

Answer (score 3):

> Will the Work Manager run the process at background, and keep retrying
>   the process even when there is no Internet Connection? and only
>   complete and stop the process until there is an Internet Connection
>   and complete the data upload?

So because you've specified that a work manager requires Network Connection.

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(RequestWorker::class.java)
                            .setConstraints(constraints)
                            .build()
```

The work request will not be triggered until there is a Network Connection, see it as the **WorkManager** listening for a change in NetworkState and once the Network is CONNECTED it starts processing your workRequest(doWork).

I must also add that while your phone is on AirPlane mode and your phone reboots with a pending **work request**, i currently don't think the work request is guaranteed to start processing immediately as you might expect, even when NetWork state is CONNECTED.